# Performance comparison of result set extracting data using index vs column name

Tags: java, resultset

Would there be a difference in performance when i use index to get data vs column name and I am talking about doing this operation a millions of times a day in the server.

`rs.getString(1)` vs `rs.getString("columnname");`

EDIT: 
JDBC version
Oracle JDBC driver
10.2.0.4.0

Comment: Would it depend on the exact version of the JDBC driver?  You'll probably need to make your own benchmark.

Comment: I think by column name will have little (negligible) overhead  of calculating index, interesting question. Let us see what experts comes with.

Comment: I'm trying to imagine a database driver where the cost of looking up a column-index by name, or vice versa, can come anywhere near the cost of retrieving the data from the database. Would it be because they designed the database incredibly well, or the driver incredibly poorly?

Answer (score 12, accepted):

The `rs.getString(n);` will perform slightly faster, because it's retrieving directly from a collection, rather than searching.

Hundreds of future readers of your code will appreciate the `rs.getString("columnname");` rather than having to look up the SQL to see what the index `n` refers to.

Answer (score 4):

It doesn't really matter.  The hit to the database will be many many times slower than accessing the column values.

`rs.getString(n)` will be negligibly faster.  However, it's going to depend on the driver implementation and number of columns in the result.  Most implementations will likely use a [HashMap](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/HashMap.html) to map column names to an index, but not necessarily.  Also, some drivers may build the HashMap lazily which means the first row will be the slowest to access by column name.  JTDS, as an example, does a linear search for columns not yet in its HashMap.

EDIT: minor edits and rearranged.  No content change.